# Find first sublist that has all numbers from 1 to K

Tags: prolog

I need to find the first sublist having all numbers from 1 to K and return it and its length.

Sorry in advance for the bad editing

---

So I check if 1 to K is in sublist if not then I delete the element (Hd) from

NumList ,append it to our result(SubList) and recursively call the function

with the tail as our new List to check.

```
findFirstSubListHavingAllColors( NumList, [Hd|Tl] ,SubList, X):-
   (   oneToKinSub(SubList,NumList)
   ->  length(SubList,X)
   ;   delete(NumList,Hd,NumList1),
       append(SubList,[Hd],SubList1),
       findFirstSubListHavingAllColors(NumList1,Tl,SubList1,_)
   ).

oneToKinSub(_,[]).
oneToKinSub(SubString,[Hd|Tl]) :-
   member(Hd,SubString),
   oneToKinSub(SubString,Tl).
```

---

For instance if

NumList =[1,2,3]

[Hd|Tl] =[**1,3,1,3,1,3,3,2**,2,1]

the expected result should be SubList=[1,3,1,3,1,3,3,2] and X= 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `append/3` and `subtract/3` to obtain the first sublist that contains all items:

```
findFirstSubListHavingAllColors( NumList, List ,SubList, Len):-
  once((
   append(SubList, _, List),        % get SubList
   subtract(NumList, SubList, []),  % test whether NumList is contained in SubList
   length(SubList, Len)
  )).
```

`once/1` here is to avoid getting other (wrong) solutions on backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using **aggegate_all/3**

```
firstSubList(NumList,  In, Out) :-
    aggregate_all(max(E),(member(X, NumList), once(nth1(E, In, X))), Len),
    length(Out, Len),
    append(Out, _, In).
Once/1 is used because numbers may appears many times in the list !
```

Comment: it won't work correctly if there is an item in `NumList` that is not in `In`.

Comment: I was trying to find a way to solve a problem and seems like my approach is difficult to make and also very costy. May I sent you the problem?

Comment: I don't think that it's a good idea ! Post your questions on S.O. Anybody can help you and you are sure to get the best answer

Comment: @gusbro>> You're right, didn't understand your remark sorry !